# How to fetch the text after <span>

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 var items = $(".landingpage .tableCol-33:nth-child(3) tbody:nth-child(even) tr td");
      $.each(items, function(i, val){
      var item = $(val);
         var next_text = item.text().substring(14, 30);
          var sub_text = item.find('a').html();
          var new_text=sub_text.substring(item.find('a').html().lastIndexOf("</span>"),sub_text.length);
        item.find("a").text(next_text);

   })
});
```

I have the above lines of code to achieve this:

Structure is as below:`<Expand collapse icon>SUbcategory:Mutual FUnds`

HTML

```
<td colspan="100" nowrap="nowrap" class="ms-gb">
    <a href="javascript:" onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('13-1_', 'img_13-1_',event, false);return false;">
    <span class="ms-commentcollapse-iconouter">
    <img class="ms-commentcollapse-icon" src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23" alt="expand" id="img_13-1_"></span>
    Subcategory</a> : Mutual Funds <span style="font-weight: lighter; display: inline-block;">(4)</span>
</td>
```

I have to replace the subcategory with mutual funds leaving the icon as it is.

Comment: can you post html sample? or a jsfiddle perhaps

Comment: <td colspan="100" nowrap="nowrap" class="ms-gb"><a href="javascript:" onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('13-1_', 'img_13-1_',event, false);return false;"><span class="ms-commentcollapse-iconouter"><img class="ms-commentcollapse-icon" src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23" alt="expand" id="img_13-1_"></span>Subcategory</a> : Mutual Funds <span style="font-weight: lighter; display: inline-block;">(4)</span></td>

Comment: This is in sharepoint environment so i m unable to create a demo.

Comment: What is the problem? Is it how to fetch `: Mutual Funds` that is after the `<a>`-tag or something else?

Comment: Question is not clear enough.